# Unable to solve the Menu bar issue using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to Framework and i have an issue with me sidebar which is showing Table tab as default but it should not show any `tab's page` as clicked. By default it should show nothing. When we click on a particular tab then it should show color on the tab of the sidebar. If i give `-1` then the color is getting disappeared on the menu tab but the Tab's page remain as it is. Is it possible to give `pathname`. how to fix by giving id ? . If Yes Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Here is the code:

```
<Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <List>
          {["table", "home"].map((item, index) => {
            const Icon = itemsConfig[item].icon;
            return (
              <ListItem
                component={Link}
                to={itemsConfig[item].link}
                selected={selectedIndex === index}
                onClick={event => handleListItemClick(event, index)}
                button
                key={item}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Icon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={itemsConfig[item].text} />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
```

Here is whole code: "https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-browser-ecz7z"

Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: My first answer got deleted, because it wasn't explained well, and contained just the link with the result. Please see it and re-accept and upvote it again.

Answer (score 0):

Define your state, that holds the selected index in your `<Layout />` component. Define function that manipulate that state and pass it to  , `<Home /> and``components along with the newly defined state. Finally call the function after the initial rendering of the component. For the`  (class component) use:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setTabIndex(this.props.index);
  }
```

For the `<Table />` use:

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.setTabIndex(props.index);
}, []);
```

The full result is posted here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-mountain-hlhk8?